# High Side and Low Side MOSFET Driver... with low supply voltage

Tags: mosfet, driver, brushless-dc-motor

I need to drive a pair of N channel MOSFETs, one on the high side of the load and one on the low side of a load. Most ICs I can find for this application require 10V+ supply voltage to get the the chip to fit in recommended operating conditions.

The VCC at the top side of the N channel is a LiPo, single cell battery (~3.2 to 4.2 V).

The inputs into the driver needs to operating around 3.3V (from outputs of a micro controller), to complicate the requirements even further.

Does anyone know where I can find such an IC? The high side/low side does not necessarily need to be in a single package. The current draw from the MOSFEts are about 3A at VCC.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this [MIC5014](http://www.micrel.com/_PDF/mic5014.pdf) driver chip will work for you